# Log in to use your Facebook account with <app-name> does not appear on mobile

Tags: facebook, mobile, authentication

I have been struggling with this for some time now.  My Log in and authenticating work fine but when a user clicks the connect button and has to log into my app the "app name" does not appear on the facebook log in page.  Makes it look a sketchy.  Work fine on desktop but does not show up on mobile.

Here is a link. i.imgur.com/2Qf17R5.png

Here is my code...

```
<!-- FB Script -->
<script src="//connect.facebook.com/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  FB.init({
  appId: '3xxxxxxxxx',
  version: 'v2.2',
  channelUrl : 'http://www.gohella.com/channel.html', // Channel File
  oauth : true,
  cookie: true,
  status: true, 
  xfbml: true
  });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
     if (response.status === 'connected') {
     var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
     var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
     window.location = "home.html";
       }

  });
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function () {
      window.location = "home.html";
  }); 

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

// Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
// successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
function testAPI() {
 console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
   console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
   document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
     'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
 });
}     
 </script>
```

This is my button code...

```
<fb:login-button size="xlarge" autologoutlink="true" scope="public_profile, user_friends" onlogin="checkLoginState();">Log In</fb:login-button>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have screen shots of what is happening? It's hard to fully tell from your description.

Comment: I don't have enough point to add an image but here is a link.

http://i.imgur.com/2Qf17R5.png

Comment: The1Fitz did you have any recommendations?

Comment: That is just saying that you have to log into to Facebook first before you can accept the request of the app.

Comment: Right.  I've logged into other apps that show the app name.  Some thing like "Please log into <app name>".  I was wondering how they do that on mobile since it shows it on desktop.